# VBScript on checking if the records exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, filesystems

I have a table and a text file. Once the records in the table copied into textfile, the records will be deleted. But the table  are still in used and will be inserted with a new records from time to time(by another program). I what to do checking on **How to make sure that if there are no records in the table, the program will never copy into textfile.**

Any solution, or references are very thankful. Thank you very much. Im testing in WSH and using MSSQL Server 2005.

```
'call functions
  call CopyFile()
  call tblDelete()

Sub tblDelete()
    Dim sql1
    sql1 = "DELETE from tblOutbox"
    rs = conn.Execute(sql1)
End Sub

Sub CopyFile
   'set the sql command
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblOutbox"
    cmd.CommandType = 1 ''# adCmdText Command text is a SQL query
    Dim rs : Set rs = cmd.Execute
   'create obj for the FileSystem
    Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim objFile, objFolder

    Dim strDir, strFile
    strDir = "c:\"
    strFile = "\newFile.txt"
   'check that the strDirectory folder is exist
    If objFSO.FolderExists(strDir) Then
       Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDir)
    Else
       Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
       WScript.Echo "Just created " & strDir
    End If
    If objFSO.FileExists(strDir & strFile) Then
       Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDir)
    Else
       Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDir & strFile)
       Wscript.Echo "Just created " & strDir & strFile
    End If 
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
   'open files and copy into

    Dim objtextStream : Set objtextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDir & strFile, 8, True)
    Do Until rs.EOF 
       objtextStream.Write rs("id") & ", "

       objtextStream.Write rs("ip") & ", "
       objtextStream.Write rs("msg") & ", "
       objtextStream.WriteLine rs("date")

       rs.MoveNext
    Loop
        objTextStream.WriteLine
        objTextStream.WriteLine "Report Generate at " & Now
        objTextStream.WriteLine "--------------------------------------------"
    objtextStream.Close 
    rs.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put

```
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
   exit sub
End If
```

before

```
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objFile, objFolder
```

i.e. Don't execute any of the statements, if there are no records.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set your code up in a format such as the following, in which you delay opening the output file until after you have fired your query and retrieved at least one response:

```
Set up SQL statement 
Execute SQL query 
init bFirstRecord as true 
Loop over results   
  if bFirstRecord
   check folder and file existence, create as necessary
   open output file
   bFirstRecord = false   
  end if   
  write record to output 
End Loop
Close up files, etc
```